# what does extent mean for the function circle?

Tags: python, python-turtle

```py
from turtle import Turtle,Screen
t=Turtle()
s=Screen()
t.left(20)
from cmath import pi
print(pi)
circle=2*pi*40
print("circle=",circle)
t.circle(radius=50,extent=2*pi*50)
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? Did you try changing the value passed to `extent` to see what happens?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to change using extent=pi*50**2. I've understood I can draw a part of the circle. If I use for extent a blank space it returns a complete circle.

Comment: Okay. Did you try using a small number, like, say, 0.1?

Comment: I didn't use a small number..but I've understood I can use the values of an angle. I used the values from 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: Okay, and what happened when you used those values? Were you able to see the effect? And again, what did the documentation tell you?

Comment: This example is with 360 degrees and it returns a complete circle. 'from turtle import Turtle,Screen
t=Turtle()
s=Screen()
t.left(20)                                                                               t.circle(radius=50,extent=360) '

Comment: I believed the extention was the value of perimeter or area..Infact I used the perimeter in this script and it returns a spirograph.

Comment: 'from turtle import Turtle,Screen
s=Turtle()
o=Screen()

from math import pi
p=pi
s.color("pink")
s.width(2)
s.speed(5)
s.penup()
s.goto(0,-100)
s.pendown()
for i in range(0,60):
    s.left(43)
    s.circle(radius=100,extent=100*2*p)
    if i in range(0,10):
        s.color("pink")
    elif i in range(10,20):
        s.color("orange")
    elif i in range(20,30):
        s.color("red")
    elif i in range(30,40):
         s.color("green")
    elif i in range(40,50):
        s.color("purple")
    elif i in range(50,60):
        s.color("brown")
o.mainloop() '

Answer (score 0):

[turtle docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) says that

```
turtle.circle(radius, extent=None, steps=None)
```

> Draw a circle with given radius. The center is radius units left of the turtle; extent – an angle – determines which part of the circle is drawn. If extent is not given, draw the entire circle. If extent is not a full circle, one endpoint of the arc is the current pen position. Draw the arc in counterclockwise direction if radius is positive, otherwise in clockwise direction. Finally the direction of the turtle is changed by the amount of extent.
>
> As the circle is approximated by an inscribed regular polygon, steps
> determines the number of steps to use. If not given, it will be
> calculated automatically. May be used to draw regular polygons.